# Referencing an observablecollection from the class

Tags: c#

I have a class called `NewsEntry` and news entry is part of an observable collection called `NewsItems`.

What I want to do is create two functions inside `NewsEntry` called `following` and `previous`.

in pseudo-c# it needs to do this.

```
public class NewsEntry {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }

    public NewsEntry following () {
       // get the ObservableCollection containing this
       // find the index of this in the collection
       // return the next item
    }

    public previous ...
}

public ObservableCollection<NewsEntry> NewsItems { get; set; }
```

can I do this from the Entry class or should I really do this from the outside class and pass a `NewsEntry` as a parameter (which I think results in ugly code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can add a static method in NewsEntry class

```
public class NewsEntry
{
    pubilc static NewsEntry following(ObservableCollection<NewsEntry> NewsItems)
    {
        //your logic
        return newsEntry;
    }

    //similarly for previous
}
```

As you said you can also create a `NewsEntryHelper` class and add methods for `following` and `previous` but I don't think it will worth in this case

Comment: is passing the collection as a parameter the only option? it looks like i'm going to have to pass the collection to the entry or the entry to the collection, which looks nasty. just wanting a cleaner option.

Comment: You can move the methods to class which contains `NewsItems`. Assuming that class will also have some kind of `CurrentItem` then you won't have to pass anything. If you don't have `current item` in that class then you only have two options as you already said

Comment: It's simple enough in order to solver my problem to send the collection to the function, i was hoping for a language feature that could enable a `.parent` type of functionality.